# Adding an Illusion of 3D Depth to a 2D Chart using Plotly in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, 3d, plotly

I'm currently working on a data visualization project in React, using the Plotly library to create interactive charts. I'd like to enhance the visual appeal of a 2D chart by giving it an illusion of 3D depth, similar to the effect achieved in the example image linked below:[kind of graph i want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cpBZ.png)

I want to clarify that I'm not looking to create a full-fledged 3D plot; rather, I'm interested in a technique that adds a faux 3D effect to a 2D chart, making it appear as though it's popping out of the screen.

I've been exploring Plotly's documentation and examples, but I haven't come across a straightforward way to achieve this effect. It's possible that I'm missing something, or there might be some clever CSS or configuration tweaks that can create this illusion.

Could someone provide guidance or code snippets on how to apply a faux 3D effect to a 2D chart using Plotly in a React application? I'd appreciate any insights into whether this can be accomplished purely through Plotly's features or if additional CSS styling is required.

Thank you for your assistance!